# Automating the reizing of different size images to a 300px by 200px image size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, imagemagick

I have various size images, some tall and wide others wide and tall, all with different image dimensions.

Is there a platform where I can dump all these images and they will be resized to fit into a 300px x 200px image box with a white or transparant background.

I think i used Imagemagic a few years ago but not sure if this feature is now part of image manipulation software as standard now or whether this can be done online using a service Dropbox with LFTTT or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done in Photoshop, but here is an alternative that may be easier for this purpose.

1. Download FastStone from faststone.org
2. Launch to program, navigate to the folder where the files you want processed are
3. Select the files you like processed, then press F3 (or right-click/tools/batch convert)
4. You will see the selected files in a window on the right
5. Click on Advanced Options and make the selections as shown in the screen capture below
6. When you return to the previous screen, select a target folder to place the processed images
7. Let it rip!

You will also find more in FastStone documentation. I have been using it for many years as my image viewer and simple processing. It is free, but consider making a donation to the developer, whom I do not know.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using GIMP, add the David's Batch Processor plugin. It's available from [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gimpdbpplugin/) and the [developer's website](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbp.html/).

It handles a number of batch resizing tasks, including resizing, conversions to different formats, batch file renaming (adding a prefix or suffix to filenames), and much more. It's a free plugin and donations are accepted on the developer's site.

[image]